# How to review macOS 10.12 Server documentation without installing?

Tags: osx-server, documentation

I can't find any **substantial documentation for macOS 10.12 Sierra Server** with Google.

I've got a couple tutorials (which are entirely useless for my needs), a bunch of marketing info, but what **I'm looking for are the PDFs that used to be shipped** with every previous version. Or websites with the same thing would be fine. Even a gopher site would be fine.

I'm gathering that some of this is in the Mac Help after installation, but the thing is, I'm researching and brainstorming our **migration checklists so we don't break anything**. Would be awfully nice to know what I'm doing before I actually install anything.

(Crosspost from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8070144 because I need this asap)

Comment: Can you please specify what information you are looking for _exactly_? Do you need the hardware requirements, port numbers, supported file formats or something else? There is no PDF bundled with macOS server 10.12 in my installation.

Comment: The main thing I need is sufficient details about migration from 10.9, and UI/feature changes since, so I can come up with a checklist that I know won't bork our existing services after upgrading. The link provided in the first answer is what I was asking about; I guess if I need more information, I'll just need to set up a test server, which is rather more trouble than I was hoping to go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not bundle any PDFs with macOS 10.12 Sierra Server.

A standalone macOS 10.12 Sierra Server installer does not exist. Server.app is just an app which is downloaded from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-server/id883878097).

[image: macOS Server App icon]

The 'Help' Menu in Server.app has an entry called 'Server Help' which forwards to https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/index.html .

The macOS server [requirements](http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/#/apd3C1D37AC-A467-4B42-A0DB-D05BADC64C3E) are available in the Server Help as well. The checklist [Install macOS Server](http://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/#/apdBD193671-D5A6-4183-A888-11A4358321DD) may be helpful as well.

Comment: For future reference: the link https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/ will redirect to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The official macOS Server documentation can be found online via Apples website, latest version being here: https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.3/